# How to make button be visible only at the end of recycler view?

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-recyclerview, main-activity

I have managed to make button visible all the time, this is ugly.

According to new material design we should use RecyclerView not ListView, so i wonder how to make buttons only appear when user scrolls to the end of the list, but not visible all the time.

In addition, recycler view can't be rendered in studio because of some open issue 72217. So I can't see how elements buttons and recycler view align with each other

[image: kkkkk]

mainActivity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include android:id="@+id/app_bar" layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_previous"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:minHeight="25dp"
    android:minWidth="70dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_next"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:minHeight="25dp"
    android:minWidth="70dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next"/>
<view
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"/>
```

2nd issue: I can only see one FORWARD button, not 2 buttons, even though I declared both in the code above and used 
attribute **alignParentright = true and alignParentLeft=true** for both forward backward buttons.

Answer (score 1):

1. RecyclerView plus button

I see two different solutions for that, first one is you place the RecyclerView and the button inside of a ScrollView disabling the RecyclerView vertical scroll and the scroll will be managed by the ScrollView. It would be like the code below:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/partner_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <view
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_next"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:minHeight="25dp"
            android:minWidth="70dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The second option would be to use setVisibility once the scroll of the recycler view is at thbe bottom, [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html) should help you to sort this option.

2. Only see one button

The reason is because you have in both buttons width as match_parent, one is hidden the other one, if you set the width as wrap_content it will be there.

Comment: @Israel_Menis, the scroll view tag does not work... the thing is: my scroll view tag is in another file book details - next layout that shows every book's image and title and other details.... the app was already scrollable but because of the scroll view for card view in bookdetails.xml

Comment: A full understanding of your layout is needed to see the best solution, anyway, the second option (use setVisibility for the button within Scroll listener) should work.